# Stabilizing express session on AppEngine Node.js Standard environment

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, express-session, google-appengine-node

I have implemented session mechanism in my app on GAE node.js standard environment using express-session without `store` value. Though it works without problems on localhost, session seems to be terminated regardless of how `cookie.maxAge` is configured on GAE node.js standard environment. This is what I have:

```
app.use(session({
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 31536000000, // 1 year
    secure: true
  },
  secret: SECRET,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

I assume this is caused by GAE not persisting memory and if so, I should add `store` option. I looked for an easiest option and found memcache, but it's [not yet available on GAE node.js standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/memcache/).

1. Is this a problem of the app not having `store` option?
2. What is the easiest way to have a `store` on GAE node.js standard?
3. How can I use memcache on this environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that memory is not persistent in the App Engine standard environment: requests arriving to the same instance will be able to re-use memory, however, your app might run on many instances and these are anyway ephemeral.

GCP does not yet offer a memcache solution from Node.js on App Engine. The current recommendation is to use a third party solution like Redis Labs Memcache (see [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-redislabs-memcache))
Once you have configured a memcache instance, you should be able to use a `MemecachedStore` for your express session. See [this sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/blob/master/tutorials/express-memcached-session-appengine/server.js)

Another alternative could be to use Cloud Datastore to store sessions. See the [nodejs-datastore-session](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore-session) node module. I have not tried it myself.

Comment: By using Datastore, the problem seems to have been solved. Thanks!

Comment: Happen to know if this package also works with Firestore?